# How can a thread release a lock if it does not hold the lock, in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I am trying to understand why my code works. I use locks for Synchronization in an attempt to solve a Leetcode problem that ensures printing functions in an order.

```
from threading import Lock, current_thread
from concurrent import futures

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.first_lock = Lock()
        self.second_lock = Lock()
        self.first_lock.acquire()
        self.second_lock.acquire()
        print(f'{current_thread()} in __init__')

    def first(self, printFirst: 'Callable[[], None]') -> None:
        # printFirst() outputs "first". Do not change or remove this line.
        print(f'{current_thread()} in first')
        printFirst()
        self.first_lock.release()


    def second(self, printSecond: 'Callable[[], None]') -> None:
        print(f'{current_thread()} in second')
        with self.first_lock:
            # printSecond() outputs "second". Do not change or remove this line.
            printSecond()
            self.second_lock.release()


    def third(self, printThird: 'Callable[[], None]') -> None:
        print(f'{current_thread()} in third')
        with self.second_lock:
            # printThird() outputs "third". Do not change or remove this line.
            printThird()

def printFirst():
    print("First")

def printSecond():
    print("Second")

def printThird():
    print("Third")

foo = Foo()
# foo.first_lock.
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    to_do: list[futures.Future] = []
    to_do.append(executor.submit(foo.third, printThird))
    to_do.append(executor.submit(foo.second, printSecond))
    to_do.append(executor.submit(foo.first, printFirst))
    
print("all set?")
```

The problem can be found [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/print-in-order/description/) and my doubt is:

`foo` is instantiated in the main thread, so `main` holds the locks? If so, it never releases it and how can another thread executing the function `first` release the lock?

Comment: "How can a thread release a lock if it does not hold the lock, in Python?" - [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock.release) clearly says that `.release()` can be called by any thread: "This can be called from any thread, not only the thread which has acquired the lock."

Comment: How is that possible, even if written in the documentation, that a thread can release locks without owning it?

Comment: Acquiring a lock just sets a flag in the lock object. Releasing the lock clears the flag and possibly notifies the waiters. Nothing bounds this operation to be performed from the owner thread. (In some programming languages/frameworks releasing a lock is required to be performed from owner thread. This is done mainly for avoid complex synchronization patterns, where a novice user has a high chance to make a mistake.)

Comment: @AviralSrivastava "How is that possible, even if written in the documentation, that a thread can release locks without owning it?"
  The concept of locking has nothing to do with ownership. Locking means "atomic change of the flag(int?) using cpu hardware".  It's better to think about it as if it's a protocol, gentlemen's agreement between control flow units(threads for example). And that agreement declares that if you get 0 as a result from test-and-set instruction, you can proceed with execution.

Comment: What prevents your thread from ignoring the test-and-set result value is "try_lock" function implementation you are using.